# Set Delegate From the Declaring View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates

I need to set my delegate, but can't see how I can, or at least aren't succeeding currently. This is what my storyboard looks like:

> ViewController 1 > Modal Presentation > NavigationController >
>   ViewController 2 > ViewController 3

I declare my delegate/protocol in ViewController 3. I need ViewController 1 to use this delegate. This way I can send messages back from 3 to 1.

My problem: How do I set the delegate? I have attempted the code below in ViewController 3 with no luck.

```
ViewController1 *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EquipmentVC"];
    delegate = vc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just get the navigation controller's presenting view controller?

Something like:

```
delegate = self.navigationController.presentingViewController;
```

Comment: I've given this a shot, but regardless, the presenting view controller is always my initial view controller, maybe because I am using a view controller container?

Comment: viewcontroller3 is the container? or which one? i'm sure that this must be the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll start again (as I never thought it was valid, so never mentioned it). RootVC > Container of TabBarController > VC1 (a tabbed vc) > Modally present nag controller > vc2 > vc3.

Comment: No matter where I try it, the presenting controller is RootVC. I can only guess, but would this be because it has a container which then contains every other view?

Comment: I take it you managed to get the view controller you searched for?

Comment: Yep just had to work through the chain. It was just confusing that the presenting view controller wasn't what I expected, probably due to how I am using a container.